# How do you resolve "backup or restore already running" message in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: backup, sharepoint-2010

I'm working on a SP2010 instance that keeps displaying a message "backup or restore already running" when viewing the backup / restore status screen.

The readyness check registers "No backup or restore in progress."

Is there a way to resolve this issue (perhaps using a powershell command)?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out [Backup through Central Admin fails; works using stsadm](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/89e44547-9686-4a68-acfb-6112e0e8f67c)